# Creating an object with a reference to the object that created it

Tags: python, object

I have a program where an object creates another object. However, the second object that gets created needs to be able to access the first. Is this possible?

EG (pseudocode)

```
class parentObject():
    parentVar = 1
    # Create Child
    x = childObject()

class childObject():
    #Assign Var to the Var of the childs parent
    childVar = parent.parentVar    

>>> x.childVar = 1
```

is there a straitforward way to do this?

UPDATE:

I don't want to inheret the class, I need to be able to access the actual object that created it, as each object created from that class has different values.

Comment: Yes, you _do_ want to inherit the class. You want the subclass to _inherit_ those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a reference to the "parent" class, but inheritance is illogical, consider sending `self` in to the constructor:

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.furniture = []

    def add_chair(self):
        self.furniture.append(Chair(self))

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} with {}'.format(self.name, self.furniture)


class Chair:
    def __init__(self, room):
        self.room = room
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Chair in {}'.format(self.room.name)


r = Room('Kitchen')
r.add_chair()
r.add_chair()

print r
print r.furniture[0]
```

**Output:**

```
Kitchen with [<__main__.Chair instance at 0x01F45F58>, <__main__.Chair instance at 0x01F45F80>]
Chair in Kitchen
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not inherit the class?

```
class parentObject():
    parentVar = 1

class childObject(parentObject):
    childVar = parentObject.parentVar

>>> x = childObject()
>>> print(x.childVar)
1
```

If you are going to have different instances of the class, you should do it as this instead:

```
class parentObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parentVar = 1

class childObject(parentObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(childObject, self).__init__()
        self.childVar = self.parentVar

>>> x = childObject()
>>> print(x.childVar)
1
```

Comment: Because each object created from that class will have different values. I dont need to access the class, but the object..

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand, In that case, I will update my answer